# Is it possible to update an Object within a Mongoose document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a weird problem with mongoose, and I'm starting to suspect that I'm doing something wrong.

My schema looks something like this:

```
var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String, // Self-e
  info: { type: Object, default: {'value':'result'} },
  created_on: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

After fetching the document, I've tried to edit the `info` object like so (pretending that `person` is the fetched document):

```
person.info['value2'] = 'result2'
person.save()
```

These changes don't show up in the DB, and I'm getting no errors when running it. Any ideas?

Comment: You tell mongoose that it is an object and nothing more, it will not infer the type from a default. So what you have here is a mixed type , meaning you will have to mark it as modified manually before saving.

Comment: @ippi How do I do that?

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html,   
but the better solution to complete your schema. dont set a type on the object, but on the child  properties, you can nest them.

Answer (score 1):

As I learned from @ippi, because `info` is a mixed Object, you need to make sure that Mongoose knows it was modified so that it will save when you call `person.save()`

For example:

```
person.info['value2'] = 'result2'
person.markModified('info')
person.save()
```